# Plot or Display chart selectively using data from the column(s) selected using ComboBox in Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

How an I create a ComboBox that will list the column headers to choose and use it to selectively plot data from one to many selected column(s) as  scatter plot chart overlays?

Comment: What have you tried? Please post the code you have developed and highlight where/why it isn't working.

Comment: I am trying to help fellow scientist to anlayse absorption spectra data from spectrophotometer . The data is ~10500 points per spectrum and about 96 spectra per run. I am able to manually select column headers, create combobox and  plot charts and do other things like minimize data by 90% without compromising on spectrum shape, auto identify peaks/troughs in specific regions, create a free moving reference line for manual analysis of peaks/troughs, assign values for peaks/troughs and create heat map. Want to dynamically choose columns to plot scatter/ line plots from a drop down menu.

Comment: You've tagged Excel and VBA so I ask again "What have you tried?" If you think a purely Excel solution may work then give a sample of your inputs, formulas used and expected outputs. If VBA is needed then post some code! SO isn't a place where you can ask for formulas or code to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I looked into various posts here, and especially of Jon Peltier  and solved the issues. I came out with a solution to time bin and squeeze the data by 95% without compromising on the spectrum shape. I was looking only for some ideas here and figured out myself most of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a couple tutorials on this topic: [*Simple Interactive Charts in Excel*](http://peltiertech.com/simple-interactive-charts-excel/) and [*Interactive Charts with Checkboxes and Formulas*](http://peltiertech.com/interactive-charts-with-checkboxes-and-formulas/).

Comment: Thanks Jon! Your tutorials were very useful in getting an idea to construct interactive chart.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2013 (and 2016) have the ability to filter out some series in your chart. You can click the filter icon floating near the top right of the chart, then uncheck some series you do not wish to display.

In addition, in Excel 2013+, you can access the Select Data dialog from the ribbon or by right-clicking on the chart, and each series listed in the dialog has a checkbox that you can use in the same way.